# Task Scheduler return code 2147942401

Tags: batch, windows-task-scheduler

I use this scheduled task for years and it always worked fine. Something weird happened a few weeks ago.
This task executes .bat file which launch python script.
It runs as administrator.
A few weeks ago it started fail with return code `2147942401`.

**Note:** if I execute it manually by click on 'Run' or from prompt it always succeed.

The are a lot of articles related to this error and I've tried all of it but it still failed. Hence I'm confused what happened.
Here are the things I've tried to change and none of it fixed the issue:

- Change options on 'General' Tab
- Change time of execution. Note: it's scheduled to run daily once but I've tried to set it to run hourly for the day and it succeeded only 2-3 times
- Change 'Action' Tab parameters
- Create a new Task

Many other things but none of it worked.
Do you have any clue what else could cause the issue to fail the Task that worked for years?
Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe export the task to XML, Pastebin and link it in the question?

Comment: Has the administrator account password changed? The task will run on the schedule using credentials entered when the task was saved. You might need to refresh the credentials of the administrator account on the scheduled task.

Comment: Administrator account did not change for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'm taking back my question and folks could disregard it because I found the issue.
Actually after investigation I found that the problem was not with Task Scheduler and .bat file. The root of the issue was that one of the parameters that python script executed via .bat file has changed the value. After I fixed the issue with that parameter I don't observe that weird behavior.
Thanks